# LUKS2 dm-integrity

Tags: integrity, luks

I am using Debian 9.5, Linux Kernel 4.16, I would like to use the dm-integrity feature with cryptsetup.

```
cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 <device> --cipher aes-gcm-random --integrity aead
```

Nevertheless, I can not figure out how to get the dm-integrity module in the Debian distro.

Are there any other ways otherwise to get crypt + integrity on a Linux partition?

**Note** - This won't be a bootable disk.

Comment: Do you mean kernel 3.16, 4.16, 4.9, or something else entirely?

Comment: My apologies, nightly writings...It is indeed kernel v4.16 from debian 9.5 distro.

Answer (score 8):

The [`dm-integrity`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-integrity.html) authenticated encryption support for block devices is part of the Linux kernel since [version 4.12](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.12#Block_layer).

If it's enabled in your kernel then it should be automatically loaded, when needed.

You can check if your kernel has this feature enabled by verifying its config, for example on a Fedora system:

```
$ grep DM_INTEGRITY /boot/config-4.17.12-100.fc27.x86_64
CONFIG_DM_INTEGRITY=m
```

Here it's compiled as a module.

Then check if the module is actually available, e.g.:

```
$ find /usr -name 'dm-integrity.ko*'
/usr/lib/modules/4.17.12-100.fc27.x86_64/kernel/drivers/md/dm-integrity.ko.xz
```

If it's not available you can query which package provides that file, e.g. something like:

```
$ apt-file search 'dm-integrity.ko*' # on Debian
$ dnf provides '*dm-integrity.ko*' # on Fedora
```

Note that (as of cryptsetup 2.0) the authenticated encryption support [is marked as experimental](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/4a2da4b51e707d0c820cec2d24be21fdd800df8f/docs/v2.0.0-ReleaseNotes#L184). Also, the release notes warn about using `aes-gcm-random`:

> DO NOT USE in production! The GCM mode uses only 96-bit nonce, and possible collision means fatal security problem.

It's thus better to use one of the other examples from the release notes:

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 <device> --cipher aes-xts-plain64 \
     --integrity hmac-sha256
# cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 <device> --cipher chacha20-random \
     --integrity poly1305
```

Finally, the release notes caution:

> There will be better suitable authenticated modes available soon   For now we are just preparing framework to enable it (and hopefully improve security of FDE).   FDE authenticated encryption is not a replacement for filesystem layer   authenticated encryption. The goal is to provide at least something because   data integrity protection is often completely ignored in today systems.

Comment: Thank you. It is very clear. Nevertheless the point was to get it from debian But new check show me that it seems that it was integrated in july in source version 4.17.3-1 (ref:Debian Bug report logs - #898318).